# How to check user login for error from rest API response in android?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am developing android apps. I am checking user login fetch data from rest api respons.

This is my json response

```
{
    "code": 404,
    "response": "error",
    "errors": {
        "massage": "invalid email/ or password."
    }
}
```

Here is my login user method

```
if (roleid.equals("1")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} else { 
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: where u passed username and password to api , where is the error ? please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share your code snippet :-
where you passed the user name & password?
How you used your rest api for response?